# Too Many Database Calls - NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have a method which is looping through records and performing a select on each record.
I would like some guidance so that all the queries are aggregated and sent to the db in one round trip.
I'm aware of CreateMultiQuery() and CreateMultiCriteria() methods but I'm unsure as to how I can implement in the current code below?

Thanks

```
foreach (Roll roll in attendanceRegisterRolls.Items)
                {
                    RollAttendeeUpdater attendeeUpdater = new RollAttendeeUpdater(enrolmentRepository, roll);
                    attendeeUpdater.**AddNewStudentEnrolmentsAsAttendees();**
                    attendeeUpdater.RefreshEffectiveAttendance(register);
                }

**Constructor**
public RollAttendeeUpdater(IEnrolmentRepository enrolmentRepository, Roll roll)
    {
        _roll = roll;
        _enrolments = enrolmentRepository.GetByRoll(_roll);
    }

public interface IEnrolmentRepository : IRepository<Enrolment>
{
    IEnumerable<Enrolment> GetByRoll(Roll roll);
    bool IsStudyCompleted(string resultCode);
}
public IEnumerable<Enrolment> GetByRoll(Roll roll)
    {
        var query = _session.CreateQuery(
            @"select e 
            from Enrolment e 
            join fetch e.Student 
            where e.Roll.Id.RollNumber = :rollNumber and e.Roll.Id.Year = :year
            order by e.EnrolmentStatus");

        query.SetString("rollNumber", roll.Id.RollNumber);
        query.SetString("year", roll.Id.YearAsTwoDigitString);
        return query.List<Enrolment>();
    }
public void **AddNewStudentEnrolmentsAsAttendees()**
    {

        foreach (Enrolment enrolment in _enrolments)
        {
            Student student = enrolment.Student;

            if (student.IsActive)
                if (_roll.HasAttendee(student.Id) == false)
                    _roll.AddAttendee(student, new DateTimeRange(enrolment.StudyStartDate, enrolment.StudyEndDate));
        }
    }

public virtual bool HasAttendee(string studentId)
    {
        return _attendees.Any(a => a.Student.Id == studentId);
    }
```

The AddNewStudentEnrolmentsAsAttendees() and enrolmentRepository.GetByRoll(_roll) methods return the following SQL:

```
select
 enrolment0_.id_enrolment as id1_1_0_,
 enrolledst1_.id_student as id1_10_1_,
 enrolment0_.study_start_date as study2_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.study_end_date as study3_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.id_eft as id4_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.enrolment_date as enrolment5_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.enrolment_start_date as enrolment6_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.enrolment_status as enrolment7_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.fee_band as fee8_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.id_course as id9_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.limitation_date as limitation10_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.result_date as result11_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.roll_number as roll12_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.year as year1_0_,
 enrolment0_.id_student as id14_1_0_,
 enrolment0_.result_code as result15_1_0_,
 enrolledst1_.surname as surname10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.given_names as given3_10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.preferred_name as preferred4_10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.title as title10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.gender as gender10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.tafe_international_id as tafe7_10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.active_ind as active8_10_1_,
 enrolledst1_.date_of_birth as date9_10_1_ 
from dt_modular_enrolment enrolment0_ inner join dt_student enrolledst1_ on enrolment0_.id_student=enrolledst1_.id_student 
where (
enrolment0_.roll_number=? )
and
(
    enrolment0_.year=? )
order by  enrolment0_.enrolment_status; p0 = 'AH0130',
p1 = '12'

SELECT
 attendees0_.roll_number as roll5_1_,
 attendees0_.year as year1_,
 attendees0_.id_class_attendee as id1_1_,
 attendees0_.id_class_attendee as id1_12_0_,
 attendees0_.attendance_start_date as attendance2_12_0_,
 attendees0_.attendance_end_date as attendance3_12_0_,
 attendees0_.enrolled_ind as enrolled4_12_0_,
 attendees0_.roll_number as roll5_12_0_,
 attendees0_.year as year12_0_,
 attendees0_.prospective_ind as prospect7_12_0_,
 attendees0_.student_identification as student8_12_0_ 
FROM dt_class_attendee attendees0_ 
WHERE attendees0_.roll_number=? and
 attendees0_.year=?; p0 = 'AH0130',
p1 = '12'
```

Comment: The code you currently posted doesn't contain any NHibernate queries. Can you update your question and show what your code looks like in the following method: enrolmentRepository.GetByRoll() ?

Comment: why do you use the `enrolmentRepository` in the `RollAttendeeUpdater` instead of giving it the enrolments in the constructor. Then you can batch selects together easyly

Comment: @Randy - the GetByRoll() method is shown above and is in the interface IEnrolmentRepository. I think the sql is created on AddNewStudentEnrolmentsAsAttendees()? If anyone could post a sample of their ideas I would appreciate it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give RollAttendeeUpdater the whole set of rolls to be updated - it then has enough knowledge to do some variant of GetByRoll() for all rolls at the same time.

Alternatively, let the querying be done by the caller and pass in roll and list of enrolment instead of passing the repository instance.

Comment: Thanks Oscar - Are you able to show me an example of yor answer? - Thanks